How to proof that the perpendicular vector is perpendicular to all the vectors in the span and is not zero?

Let $v_1,\dots,v_p\in\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\}$ be orthogonal and normalized. Let $V=\langle v_1,\dots,v_p\rangle$ be the span of $v_1,\dots,v_p$. Let $w\in\mathbb{R}^m\setminus V$ be another arbitrary vector, outside of $V$. Then $$w':=w-\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw)$$ is orthogonal to each of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_p$ and not zero.

Now my task is to proof this statement. I tried it like the following but I am pretty sure that I did something wrong:
To proof that $w'$ is orthogonal to each of the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_p$ I thought that I have to show that the dot product $(w')^Tv_p$ is $0$.
$$
\begin{align}
(w')^Tv_p&=(w-\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw))^Tv_p\\
&=w^Tv_p-(\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw))^Tv_p\\
&=w^Tv_p-\sum_{j=1}^p((v_j(v_j^Tw))^Tv_p)\\
&=w^Tv_p-\sum_{j=1}^p((v_j^Tv_p)((v_j^Tw)^Tv_p))\\
&=w^Tv_p-(\sum_{j=1}^p(v_j^Tv_p)(v_j^Tv_p)(w^Tv_p))\\
&=w^Tv_p-(1\cdot1\cdot(w^Tv_p))\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
The first step is just substituting $w'$ with the defintion of $w'$. The second and third step is just using the fact that the dot product is distributive. But in the fourth step I really didn't came up with a continuation so I thought that I can maybe distribute the $v_p$, but I am not really sure if that is allowed. Because in one of my linear algebra books there is only stated that the distributivity for the dot product holds for summation, but there is nothing said about multiplication.
After step $4$ I continued and again distributed the $v_p$. I am pretty sure that I am not allowed to do that, because I never saw any source where it is stated that I can distribute like I did.
The $6$th step is just using the fact that the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_p$ are orthogonal to each other. So everythin is always $0$ for $j\neq p$. And if $j=p$ then the vectors are the same so the dot product is $||v_p||^2$ and because $||v_p||=1$ also $||v_p||^2=1$. So the dot product is $1$.
You can help me if someone can explain how to correct this proof and explain me when I am allowed to use distributivity when the dot product is included.
Proofing that $w'$ is not $0$
Now I still have to proof that $w'$ is not $0$. I just did this like the following:
$$w'=w-\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw)$$
We know that $w\notin V$, so $w\neq0$ because otherwise $w\in V$ would be true. We can see that the in the sum we just scale a vector which is in $V$ so the result is in $V$ again. So the whole sum is just summing scaled versions of vectors out of $V$ so the result of the sum is in $V$ again, because it's just a linear combination. Because $w\notin V$ and (I betitle the sum with x) $x\in V$ we see that $w\neq x$ and thus $w'$ can't be $0$.
You can help me even more if you take a look over this part of the whole proof as well.

2nd Try of the proof with help of @Digitallis answer
Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $1\leq k \leq p$
We have to show that $(w')^Tv_k=0$
$$
\begin{align}
(w')^Tv_k&\overset{(1)}{=}(w-\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw))^Tv_k\\
&\overset{(2)}{=}(w^T-(\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw))^T)v_k\\
&\overset{(3)}{=}(w^T-(\sum_{j=1}^p((v_j(v_j^Tw))^T)))v_k\\
&\overset{(4)}{=}(w^T-(\sum_{j=1}^p(v_j^T(v_j^Tw))))v_k\\
&\overset{(5)}{=}(w^Tv_k)-(\sum_{j=1}^p(v_j^T\cdot(v_j^Tw))\cdot v_k)\\
&\overset{(6)}{=}(w^T-v_k)-(\sum_{j=1}^p v_j^T\cdot v_k\cdot(v_j^Tw))\\
&\overset{(7)}{=}w^Tv_k-(1\cdot v_k^Tw)\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Substituted with the definition.
Used $(u+w)^T=u^T+w^T$.
Used $(u+w)^T=u^T+w^T$ to pull the transpose operation into the sum.
Because $(v_j^Tw)$ is a scalar I used $(\alpha v)^T=\alpha v^T$.
Used distributive law $(u-v)\cdot\alpha=(u\cdot\alpha-v\cdot\alpha)$.
Used distributive law to pull $v_k$ into the sum.
If $j\neq k$ then $v_j^Tv_k=0$ and then the whole sum gets 0. So we can break down to the case where $j=k$.

At the end we can just use commutativity and see that $(w')^Tv_k=0$ holds.

To prove that $w'$ is orthogonal to $v_1,...,v_p$ you should prove that it is orthogonal to each of those vectors. Not just orthogonal to $v_p$.

Instead of guessing/making up properties you should instead use the existing ones.
$$ (\alpha v )^T = \alpha v ^T$$
$$ (v + w)^T = v^T + w^T$$
where $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $v,w \in \mathbb R^m$.
Then by using these properties we can check that $ w'$ and $v_k$ are orthogonal for each $k = 1,..., p$ by checking that $(w')^Tv_k = 0$ for each $k$.

Hint : use the fact that $ \alpha = v_j^Tw$ is a real number.


You have the right idea for the second part but you can express it much more nicely as follows:

If $w' = 0$ then we would have
$$ w = \underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^pv_j(v_j^Tw)}_{\in V}.$$
which is impossible since $w \not \in V$.


I will try to proof it as you said. If I get it done, I will accept your answer!

@DavidKrell le me know if you need an extra hint

I now added my 2nd try to proof the statement in my question. Can you take a look over it please?
